# Azure CosmosDB - Most efficient way to upload documents (size, frequency)

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to optimize my usage of Request Units. Say in a span of one minute, is it better to upload 10 0.1MB documents or a single 1MB document? I heard that if the total amount of data is the same, then the RU usage would be the same, but it makes sense to me that if I access the database to write to it more frequently then it would be more costly in terms of RUs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RU calculation is based on a variety of factors one of which is document size. Right now you're trying to do micro optimizations on RU when you **should** be designing based on your read/write patterns and ensuring that you can efficiently access the data you need. The difference between 10*0.1 and 1.0 in this case should take a backseat as the RU cost difference will be negligible.

Comment: I have designed it in a way that I can efficiently access the data I need, and whether I I choose 10*0.1 or 1.0, it does not affect the efficient access. I hope to upload data as frequently as I can (once every 30 seconds), but I have multiple active processes uploading to the same cosmosDB collection, so if that would result in an overuse of the RUs, I would rather upload data less frequently (once every 5 minutes) than pay for more RU/sec. The document size is proportional to how long I wait before uploading the document, so I would like to find out the cheaper way of doing this.

Comment: You're entirely missing the point of RU/ **second**. If you wait 5 minutes to do a batch insert you'll have way more data to push in you'll immediately exceed the RU throughput for that **second**. It is much better to establish consistent inserts to keep things cheaper